# Code changes for springboot application doesn't reflected on Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a spring boot application run in Docker and it can be run successfully. The problem is that when I update my application code, the code changes is not reflected on Docker after rebuilding the image and start the container.

Here is my Dockerfile. I try to copy the src file into the image and packaging the spring boot application on build stage. Then copy the jar generated to another stage and run the application when the container is started.

```
FROM openjdk:17 as buildstage
WORKDIR /app
COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn
COPY pom.xml .
RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline
COPY src src
RUN ./mvnw package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
COPY target/*.jar springboot-flash-cards-docker.jar

FROM openjdk:17
COPY --from=buildstage /app/springboot-flash-cards-docker.jar .
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "springboot-flash-cards-docker.jar"]
```

And this is parts of my docker-compose.yml for the spring boot application.

```
services:
    container_name: springboot
    build:
      context: ./springboot-flash-cards
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres
```

I have checked that the code in the springboot container is not updated after editing my code base. The way I check:

```
docker cp "springboot container":springboot-flash-cards-docker.jar .

java xf springboot-flash-cards-docker.jar
```

I tried to use docker compose build --no-cache to prevent docker build image from cache. But doesn't work.

Expected Behaviour: Dode changes in the spring boot application will be reflected after rebuilding the image and run inside the docker container.

Comment: @RoarS. Thanks for the reply. I have try but still doesn't work. I think it is "clean" even if I not using `RUN ./mvnw -U clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true` since there are not "old" file or class generated by maven before docker build image from the dockerfile.

Comment: In your first stage, you build the application, but then ignore that and instead `COPY` a prebuilt jar file from the host system.  Are you getting that same jar file out when you `docker cp` it out; if you manually `mvnw package` on the host do you see updates; do you need to `RUN cp ...` instead?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks, David. You are right. I was coping the jar from my host system to docker. I just edit that line to `RUN mv target/*.jar springboot-flash-cards-docker.jar` and it works fine now.

Comment: Hi, from your comments it looks like you managed to fix it. If so, please write a regular answer, because it may help others with a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the help from @DavidMaze. The problem is fixed.

Reason why problem occur:

**The `docker run` command runs a command in a new container, pulling the image if needed and starting the container.** From Docker doc

In the original Dockerfile, `RUN ./mvnw package -Dmaven.test.skip=true` build the jar file **inside the container**.
`COPY target/*.jar springboot-flash-cards-docker.jar` will copy the jar file "target/*.jar" from **the host machine** to the container. And what I expected is to move and rename the jar built i**nside the docker container**. Since I didn't package code on my host after code changes, the code changes is not reflected on docker.

How to fixed it:

Use `RUN mv target/*.jar springboot-flash-cards-docker.jar` instead of `COPY target/*.jar springboot-flash-cards-docker.jar`. This command will move and rename the
"target/*.jar" **inside the container** to "springboot-flash-cards-docker.jar".

The fixed docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:17 as buildstage
WORKDIR /app
COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn
COPY pom.xml .
RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline
COPY src src
RUN ./mvnw package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
RUN mv target/*.jar springboot-flash-cards-docker.jar

FROM openjdk:17
COPY --from=buildstage /app/springboot-flash-cards-docker.jar .
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "springboot-flash-cards-docker.jar"]
```